# How to make smaller subsets based upon a fixed number of rows repeating over the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, large-data

**My Problem:**

I have a dataframe consisting of 86016000 rows of observations:

1. there are `512000` observations for each hour
2. there are 24 hours data for seven days
3. So `24*7*512000 = 86016000`
4. there are 40 columns (variables)
5. There is no column of date or datetimestamp
6. Only row numbers are good enough to identify how many obs. for each day, and there are no errors in recording of this data.

Given such a large dataset, what I want to do is create subsets of `12288000` (i.e. `24 * 512000`) rows, so that we have 7 each day's subset.

**What I tried:**

```
d <- split(PltB_Fold3_1_Data, rep(1:12288000, each=7))
```

But unfortunately after almost half an hour, I termicated the process as there was no result.

Is there any better solution then the one above?

Comment: With that much data, I wouldn't want to make another copy of it all sliced up. I'd probably just work with the subset of interest using `df[1:12288000, ]`

Comment: Thanks @cory. Only problem here in your suggestion is I can not repeat and get 7 subsets i.e. subset1 = 1 to 12288000 rows, subset2 = 12288001 to 24576000 rows, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `seq` rather than `rep`. With `seq`, you can generate a sequence of numbers from 0 to 86016000 incremented by 12288000.

To save resources, you can then use this sequence to generate temporary data frames and do whatever you want with each.

```
sequence <- seq(from = 0, to = 86016000, by = 12288000)

for(i in 1:(length(sequence)-1)){
    temp <- df[sequence[i]+1:sequence[i+1], ]
    # do something here with your temporary data frame
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @edomt for your suggestion. it work with little tweeking.